# How to save data btnaddqty click to dbhelper save sqlite database android?

Tags: android, sqlite

How to feed data to adapter to sqlite  I have tried many times and I get errors  `databaseHandler.Addcart(items.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).category_name, items.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).recipe_id,items.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).recipe_title,items.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).recipe_time,items.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).recipe_image,items.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).recipe_description,items.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).video_url,items.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).video_id,items.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).content_type,items.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).featured,items.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).tags,items.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).total_views,items.get(holder.getAdapterPosition())._stringVal);` this data not fetch sqlite `btnaddqty` button click data not fetch sqlite

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    if (holder instanceof OriginalViewHolder) {
        final Recipe p = items.get(position);
        final OriginalViewHolder vItem = (OriginalViewHolder) holder;

        vItem.category_name.setText(p.category_name);
        vItem.recipe_title.setText(p.recipe_title);

        vItem.price.setPaintFlags(vItem.price.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);

        vItem.price.setText("₹" +p.price);

        vItem.discountprice.setText("₹" +p.discountprice);

        double price = Double.parseDouble(p.price);
        double discountprice = Double.parseDouble(p.discountprice);

        int discountPercentage = (int) (( (int) (((discountprice / price) - 1) * 100)));


        vItem.discountpricetext.setText( Integer.toString(discountPercentage)+ "%OFF");



        ((OriginalViewHolder) holder).btnaddqty.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.d("src", "Decreasing value...");
                _counter++;
                _stringVal = Integer.toString(_counter);
                vItem.value.setText(_stringVal);


                if (_counter > 0) {
                    vItem.value.setText(_stringVal);
                }


                databaseHandler = new DbHandler(context);

                databaseHandler.Addcart(items.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).category_name, items.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).recipe_id,items.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).recipe_title,items.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).recipe_time,items.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).recipe_image,items.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).recipe_description,items.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).video_url,items.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).video_id,items.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).content_type,items.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).featured,items.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).tags,items.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).total_views,items.get(holder.getAdapterPosition())._stringVal);


            }
        });
```

ADDCART

```
    public class DbHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 9;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "db_recipes_favorite";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "tbl_recipes_favorite";

    private static final String TABLE_ADDCART = "ADDCART";


    private static final String  KEY_QTY = "qty";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_CAT_NAME = "category_name";
    private static final String KEY_RECIPE_ID = "recipe_id";

    private static final String   KEY_RECIPE_price = "price";

    private static final String   KEY_RECIPE_discountprice = "discountprice";

    private static final String KEY_RECIPE_TITLE = "recipes_title";
    private static final String KEY_RECIPE_TIME = "recipe_time";
    private static final String KEY_RECIPE_IMAGE = "recipe_image";
    private static final String KEY_RECIPE_DESCRIPTION = "recipe_description";
    private static final String KEY_VIDEO_URL = "video_url";
    private static final String KEY_VIDEO_ID = "video_id";
    private static final String KEY_CONTENT_TYPE = "content_type";
    private static final String KEY_FEATURED = "featured";
    private static final String KEY_TAGS = "tags";
    private static final String KEY_TOTAL_VIEWS = "total_views";


    public DbHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + KEY_CAT_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_RECIPE_ID + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_RECIPE_TITLE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_RECIPE_TIME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_RECIPE_IMAGE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_RECIPE_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_VIDEO_URL + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_VIDEO_ID + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_CONTENT_TYPE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_FEATURED + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_TAGS + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_TOTAL_VIEWS + " TEXT"
                +KEY_QTY+"TEXT"
                + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);



        String CREATE_CONTACTS_ADDCART = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ADDCART + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + KEY_CAT_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_RECIPE_ID + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_RECIPE_TITLE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_RECIPE_TIME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_RECIPE_IMAGE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_RECIPE_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_VIDEO_URL + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_VIDEO_ID + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_CONTENT_TYPE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_FEATURED + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_TAGS + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_TOTAL_VIEWS + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_QTY+" TEXT"

                + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_ADDCART);

    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ADDCART);
        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    //Adding Record in Database

    public void AddtoFavorite(Recipe p) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_CAT_NAME, p.getCategory_name());
        values.put(KEY_RECIPE_ID, p.getRecipe_id());
        values.put(KEY_RECIPE_TITLE, p.getRecipe_title());
        values.put(KEY_RECIPE_TIME, p.getRecipe_time());
        values.put(KEY_RECIPE_IMAGE, p.getRecipe_image());
        values.put(KEY_RECIPE_DESCRIPTION, p.getRecipe_description());
        values.put(KEY_VIDEO_URL, p.getVideo_url());
        values.put(KEY_VIDEO_ID, p.getVideo_id());
        values.put(KEY_CONTENT_TYPE, p.getContent_type());
        values.put(KEY_FEATURED, p.getFeatured());
        values.put(KEY_TAGS, p.getTags());
        values.put(KEY_TOTAL_VIEWS, p.getTotal_views());

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection

    }

    // Getting All Data

    @SuppressLint("Range")
    public String CheckOrderExists(long recipe_id) {

        String count = "0";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ADDCART + " WHERE " + KEY_RECIPE_ID , new String[]{String.valueOf(recipe_id)});
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            count = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_QTY));
            if (count.equals("0")) {
                db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_ADDCART + " WHERE " + KEY_RECIPE_ID , new String[]{String.valueOf(recipe_id)});

            }
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        return count;
    }

    public void UpdateOrderData(long recipe_id,String _stringVal) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        if (_stringVal.equals("0")) {
            DeleteOrderData(recipe_id);
        } else {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(KEY_QTY, _stringVal);
            db.update(TABLE_ADDCART, values, String.valueOf(recipe_id), new String[]{String.valueOf(recipe_id)});
        }
        db.close();
    }


    public void DeleteOrderData(Long recipe_id) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        database.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_ADDCART + " WHERE " + recipe_id , new String[]{String.valueOf(recipe_id)});
        database.close();
    }

    public List<Recipe> getAllData() {
        List<Recipe> dataList = new ArrayList<Recipe>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY id DESC";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Recipe values = new Recipe();
                values.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                values.setCategory_name(cursor.getString(1));
                values.setRecipe_id(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));
                values.setRecipe_title(cursor.getString(3));
                values.setRecipe_time(cursor.getString(4));
                values.setRecipe_image(cursor.getString(5));
                values.setRecipe_description(cursor.getString(6));
                values.setVideo_url(cursor.getString(7));
                values.setVideo_id(cursor.getString(8));
                values.setContent_type(cursor.getString(9));
                values.setFeatured(cursor.getString(10));
                values.setTags(cursor.getString(11));
                values.setTotal_views(cursor.getLong(12));
                // Adding contact to list
                dataList.add(values);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return dataList;
    }

    //getting single row
    public List<Recipe> getFavRow(long id) {
        List<Recipe> dataList = new ArrayList<Recipe>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE recipe_id=" + id;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Recipe values = new Recipe();
                values.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                values.setCategory_name(cursor.getString(1));
                values.setRecipe_id(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));


                values.setRecipe_title(cursor.getString(3));
                values.setRecipe_time(cursor.getString(4));
                values.setRecipe_image(cursor.getString(5));
                values.setRecipe_description(cursor.getString(6));
                values.setVideo_url(cursor.getString(7));
                values.setVideo_id(cursor.getString(8));
                values.setContent_type(cursor.getString(9));
                values.setFeatured(cursor.getString(10));
                values.setTags(cursor.getString(11));
                values.setTotal_views(cursor.getLong(12));
                values.setComments_count(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(13)));

                // Adding contact to list
                dataList.add(values);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return dataList;
    }

    //for remove favorite
    public void RemoveFav(Recipe contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, KEY_RECIPE_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(contact.getRecipe_id())});
        db.close();
    }


    public List<Recipe> Addcart(String category_name, long recipe_id, String recipe_title, String recipe_time, String recipe_image, String recipe_description, String video_url, String video_id, String content_type, String featured, String tags, long total_views,String _stringVal) {


        try {
            if (!CheckOrderExists(recipe_id).equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                UpdateOrderData(recipe_id, _stringVal);
            } else {
                SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(KEY_CAT_NAME, category_name);
                values.put(KEY_RECIPE_ID, recipe_id);
                values.put(KEY_RECIPE_TITLE, recipe_title);
                values.put(KEY_RECIPE_TIME, recipe_time);
                values.put(KEY_RECIPE_IMAGE, recipe_image);
                values.put(KEY_RECIPE_DESCRIPTION, recipe_description);
                values.put(KEY_VIDEO_URL, video_url);
                values.put(KEY_VIDEO_ID, video_id);
                values.put(KEY_CONTENT_TYPE, content_type);
                values.put(KEY_FEATURED, featured);
                values.put(KEY_TAGS, tags);
                values.put(KEY_TOTAL_VIEWS, total_views);
                values.put(KEY_QTY, _stringVal);
                // Inserting Row
                db.insert(TABLE_ADDCART, null, values);
                db.close(); // Closing database connection
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {


        }

        return null;
    }
        public enum DatabaseManager {
            INSTANCE;
            private SQLiteDatabase db;
            private boolean isDbClosed = true;
            DbHandler dbHelper;

            public void init(Context context) {
                dbHelper = new DbHandler(context);
                if (isDbClosed) {
                    isDbClosed = false;
                    this.db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                }

            }

            public boolean isDatabaseClosed() {
                return isDbClosed;
            }

            public void closeDatabase() {
                if (!isDbClosed && db != null) {
                    isDbClosed = true;
                    db.close();
                    dbHelper.close();
                }
            }
        }

}
```